# I created a library project in angular 7.I want to use this library project in another project without publishing.Is there any way?

Tags: angular

I  created a library project in angular 7.I want to use this library project in another project without publishing.Is there any way?

Comment: Also you could use `--watch`

Comment: can you explain me

Comment: Build library project - `your_command_to_build --watch`

Comment: In another project `run your angular project` and add Import Statement for your library module

Comment: You can check this [repository](https://github.com/prashantpimpale93/ng-pmp-image-slider) Have setup with the local env. I can't help more [bit busy now]

Answer (score 0):

If you create an Angular mono repo and have the library in the same repo then you don't need to publish it as the other project can use the library from the dist folder once you have built it.

Here is a good article on it

https://nezhar.com/blog/up-and-running-library-development-with-angular-7/

If they are in different project repositories you will need some npm repo to hold the built library.

Comment: can you tell me about npm repo

Comment: An npm repo is where you publish to, as in what you are trying to avoid.